# Manipulate a slider with next and previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can this slider be manipulated so that by clicking on a button it'll go to the previous item, and next to the next item?

Currently it's possible to move between dividers through links ("1 2 3 4 5")  in the first divider, and go back to the first divider through a "back" link on each divider.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mask">
        <div id="item1" class="item">
            <a name="item1"></a>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#item1" class="panel">1</a>
                <a href="#item2" class="panel">2</a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel">3</a>
                <a href="#item4" class="panel">4</a>
                <a href="#item5" class="panel">5</a>
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
            <a name="item2"></a>
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item">
            <a name="item3"></a>
            <div class="content"><a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item4" class="item">
            <a name="item4"></a>
            <div class="content"><a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5" class="item">
            <a name="item5"></a>
            <div class="content"><a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mask {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}    
.item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.content {
    width: 45%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}       
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.panel').click(function () {
        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        current = $(this);
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });
});


function resizePanel() {
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({
        width: width,
        height: height
    });
    $('#mask').css({
        width: mask_width,
        height: height
    });
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` of the slider

Comment: @Tushar http://jsfiddle.net/ctdt2bk1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove nav links from items and create separated nav panel with buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function shift(direction) {
    var 
      $mask = $('#mask'),  
      items = $('.item').size(),
      currentItem = $mask.data('currentItem'),
      newItem;
    
    if (currentItem == undefined) {
      currentItem = 0;
    }
    
    newItem = currentItem + direction;
    $mask.data('currentItem', newItem).animate({marginLeft: -500 * newItem});
    
    if (newItem == 0) {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', false);
    }    
    if (newItem == items - 1) {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
  
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    return shift(-1);
  });
  $('#next').click(function() {
    return shift(1);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
#prev {
  left: 40px;
}
#next {
  right: 40px;
}
#mask {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}    
.item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.content {
    width: 45%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}       
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
    <button id="prev" disabled>&lt;&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button id="next">&gt;&gt;&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="mask">
    <div id="item1" class="item">
      <a name="item1"></a>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item3" class="item">
      <a name="item3"></a>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item4" class="item">
      <a name="item4"></a>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item5" class="item">
      <a name="item5"></a>
      <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution is not finished. It doesn't cosider window resizing.

Comment: Demovoy can we open a chat

Comment: demovoy how can i make it a loop, so when it passes by the last divider it'll continue to the first?

Comment: For example you can clone first item by `jQuery.clone()` and attach it in the end. After that when you click prev button on first item or next button on cloned item you need to shift whole list to cloned item (or first item) before animate.  
Also you can use one of many jQiuery carousel plugins (https://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery+carousel+plugin&oq=jquery+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i65l3j69i60.2129j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)